# error: list indices must be integers, not float', u'occurred at index 0. Python 3.x

Tags: python, typeerror

Trying to apply a tutorial to some of my own data. Tutorial link: 
https://github.com/brendonhall/facies_classification/blob/master/Facies%20Classification%20-%20SVM.ipynb

I am up to the in[3] code box.

When attempting to define the colour map for use in plotting I get the error "TypeError: ('list indices must be integers, not float', u'occurred at index 0') "

I have pasted my code below. Thanks in advance,

```
import pandas as pd

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv('BHPAND.csv')
data.describe()
data['BH'] = data['BH'].astype('category')
data['FM'] = data['FM'].astype('category')
data['SBTN'] = data['SBTN'].astype('category')
# Set names of Borehole UID's
data['BH'].unique()

# Define colours for facies based on SBTn
# 1=sensitive fine grained  2=organic clay   3=silty clay to clay 
# 4=silt mixtures 5=sand mixtures 6=sands 7=gravelly sand
# 8=very stiff sand/clay sand 9=highly overconsolidated fine grained
sbtn_colours = ['#5E5E56', '#1E1E1C','#AAAA96','#788E6D',
       '#C6C57D','#FFFC3F', '#AED6F1', '#BA4D2C', '#FF008C']
sbtn_labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
#sbtn_colour_map = dictionary that maps sbtn labels to colours
sbtn_colour_map = {}
for ind, label in enumerate(sbtn_labels):
    sbtn_colour_map[label] = sbtn_colours[ind]

def label_sbtn(row, labels):
    return labels[ row['SBTN'] -1]

data.loc[:,'sbtnLabels'] = data.apply(lambda row: label_sbtn(row, sbtn_labels), axis=1)
```

When checking my data types I can see that the SBTN is recorded as a category:

```
data.dtypes
Out[##]: 
BH       category
MD        float64
DR        float64
FM       category
RHOB      float64
M_MOD     float64
PHI       float64
RES       float64
SBTN     category
SU        float64
VP        float64
Z         float64
dtype: object
```

Is the problem here that my column SBTN is a category not an int? Basically I want to define a colour map using my hex colours for each SBTN type. In the original csv file SBTN is an integer.

Full error traceback:

```
        %run "C:\Users\black\Desktop\Pandas Facies\script1.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\black\Desktop\Pandas Facies\script1.py in <module>()
     25     return labels[ row['SBTN'] -1]
     26 
---> 27 data.loc[:,'sbtnLabels'] = data.apply(lambda row: label_sbtn(row, sbtn_labels), axis=1)
     28 
     29 

C:\Users\black\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4150                     if reduce is None:
   4151                         reduce = True
-> 4152                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
   4153             else:
   4154                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\Users\black\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4246             try:
   4247                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4248                     results[i] = func(v)
   4249                     keys.append(v.name)
   4250             except Exception as e:

C:\Users\black\Desktop\Pandas Facies\script1.py in <lambda>(row)
     25     return labels[ row['SBTN'] -1]
     26 
---> 27 data.loc[:,'sbtnLabels'] = data.apply(lambda row: label_sbtn(row, sbtn_labels), axis=1)
     28 
     29 

C:\Users\black\Desktop\Pandas Facies\script1.py in label_sbtn(row, labels)
     23 
     24 def label_sbtn(row, labels):
---> 25     return labels[ row['SBTN'] -1]
     26 
     27 data.loc[:,'sbtnLabels'] = data.apply(lambda row: label_sbtn(row, sbtn_labels), axis=1)

TypeError: ('list indices must be integers, not float', u'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: Always post the full traceback of your error when asking a question. It's important to see where the error happened.

Comment: Apologies, updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error implies that `row['SBTN']` is a float. Convert it to an integer with `int`, i.e. `labels[int(row['SBTN']) - 1]`. You may want to make sure that it really is an integer in float type first, i.e. `assert row['SBTN'] == int(row['SBTN'])`.

Comment: Yup that did it! Thanks